# Cross-Site XsltListView WebPart throws Exceptions

Tags: 2010, xslt-list-view-web-part, connected-web-parts

I Created a site with a XsltListView Webpart displaying list content from another site in the same site collection. I created it using Sharepoint Designer by exporting the Webpart from the original web to the new one.
When I click on a folder or want to send a row of data to another WebPart, an exeption is thrown, presumably because SharePoint creates URLs of folder Items or files relatively to the current web, which is of course wrong.

I read about that somewhere before but I did not find a solution. 
How do I fix this?

Exception message and stack trace if a row of data is send to another webpart:

```
Der Wert liegt außerhalb des erwarteten Bereichs. (means: Argument out of Range)

bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebRelativeUrlFromUrl(String strUrl, Boolean includeQueryString, Boolean canonicalizeUrl) 
bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.get_Url() bei Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BaseXsltListWebPart.get_ConnectionProviderDataTable() 
bei Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.get_RowData() 
bei Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetRowData(RowCallback callback) 
bei Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.IWebPartRow.GetRowData(RowCallback callback)
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you get the values of the throwing method *GetWebRelativeUrlFromUrl*? those are strUrl, includeQueryString and canonicalizeUrl? Because the bools cannot be out of range, I assume its the url. Umlauts in it?

Comment: That is inside the SharePoint code. I cannot debug on that machine.

Comment: No spaces, no umlauts no special characters in the URL.

Comment: Have you tried it with your "empty implementation" or does that error, too?

Comment: The error is thrown by the cross-site XsltListViewWebPart. I changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this before.  It is easy to do through SPD as you have, though content editors can also add a list view to a page and then move the page to a different site.  Unfortunately this can corrupt the source list - I have no idea how.  The other way it manifests is with a corruption in the Manage Content and Structure views.

The recommended fix from MS that has worked for me a few times now is to do the following:

1. Delete the remote list view
2. Delete the corrupted list
3. Restore the deleted list from the Recycle Bin

All should now be working again.

To create a view of a list on another site use a CQWP, a search web part or a web service.

Comment: I did not move the list or site, I moved the XsltListViewWebPart with SPD to another SPWeb to show the same list with another view to a specific audience. 

 I can't use CQWP because I need the "send row of data" functionality of the XsltWebPart.

Comment: Then I think your best option is to create a new SOAP or REST data source using SPD.  Create the source in the site you want to display the list view and base it on the list in the other site.